# View inside Margin Horizontal not wrapping correctly

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, flexbox

I have a view that is calling a component. The view is set to a marginHorizontal:25 with a marginHorizontal:5 in the component.

Here is the code for rendering the items:

```
<View key={i}
         style={{
            marginHorizontal: 25,
            marginBottom: 12,
            borderRadius: 5,
            backgroundColor: "red",
            paddingRight: 5,
         }}>
         <Comment
            avatar={avatars[c.owner]}
            owner={names[c.owner]}
            message={c.message}
         />
      </View>
```

Here is the code for the comment specifically:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <Image
          style={styles.avatar}
          resizeMode="cover"
          source={{ uri: avatar }}
        />
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "#EEF0F3",
            flexDirection: "column",

            marginHorizontal: 5,
            padding: 8,
            borderRadius: 17.5,
            justifyContent: "flex-end",
          }}>
          <Text style={styles.owner}>{owner}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.message}>{message}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
```

The problem that I am having is that I would like to change the first marginHorizontal to 17, however this removes the second marginHorizontal when reloading the view, making it so the text goes out of the parent view.

I was wondering if there was a way to fix this without messing with the font size of the text.

[marginHorizontal: 25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9oSz.png)

[marginHorizontal: 17](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwtqK.png)